# Multivariable Cox Regression Analysis

Tags: cox-model, multivariate-regression

I would like to know if in multivariable Cox regression analysis there is a way to yield only models that include a variable of interest (and if no model is statistically significant to just answer that).

I am studying a cell phenotype. This phenotype "high" is associated with graft loss by the log rank test and in an univariate Cox analysis (versus phenotype "low"). I have 14 demographic variables also associated with graft loss as previously published.
Now I would like to explore multivariate models. But I am interested only on models that would include my phenotype variable. If no such model is statistically significant it's fine but I want to know. I have 15 variables including my variable phenotype so I would like to be able to test all models with 2 to 15 variables that include the variable phenotype.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How many events (presumably, graft losses) are in your data set? Do you have complete data on all 15 potential predictor variables?

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as p-hacking, but I'm a stats novice so I could be wrong.

If you decide to move forward with this strategy, I would use the `My.stepwise.coxph` function in R where you can specify that you want a variable to be included in each regression using the argument `in.variable`.

Here's the link to the documentation:https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/My.stepwise/versions/0.1.0/topics/My.stepwise.coxph

Comment: Your sense that this is close to p-hacking is correct. Automated model selection like stepwise is [not a good idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/28500) in general. It's a particular problem with Cox models, that have [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) if any outcome-associated predictor is left out of the model.

Comment: Hi. OK, thanks for your answers and warnings!

Comment: @Elodie another approach to your problem, if you don't have many cases, is to include your `phenotype` as a predictor and do a ridge-regression penalization on the clinical covariates. That way you don't have to do variable selection (with its p-hacking) and you still account for all your outcome-associated variables. [Tihs paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27357163/) is an example. Or see Frank Harrell's ideas on data reduction in Section 4.7 of his [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) for how to reduce multiple clinical variables into a smaller number of predictors.